Bevel/Blend base of embossed text
i want to emboss this text and 3d print it. ive added the text just how i want it to appear, but want a smooth transition from the object to the text base.
currently the text and the object are separate things (not joined).
from the image you can see that it is a sharp interface between the two objects.
as it is intended to replicate an injection molded part, the transition from the object into the text should be bevelled from the text base.
ive slightly bevelled the text itself so its not so sharp, but dont know how to bevel where the text intersects the surface.
my other challenge is that i want the emboss to be raised the exact same amount across the object.
the object surface that thge text is embossed onto is slightly curved so the first and last letter protrudes more than the other letters. is there a way to make the text follow the geometry of the object surface?




Why not just do a Union Boolean and then you can bevel the edges

You can achieve the text following the geometry by adding a Shrinkwrap modifier to the text. Here are the settings:

Wrap Method: Target Normal Project
Snap Mode: Outside Surface
Target: (The object you want the text to stick to)
Offset: (Whatever value looks good)

For the beveling problem you can use this free Blender Market addon called Bevel Joints.

thanks Dgc.. shrink wrapping worked- ive learnt something, now trying to get the bevel joint addon to work..

Yeah I tried testing the addon for a little bit, not that much, but I couldn't get it to join without messing the geometry up
